# Update project file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use this lib

```
org.eclipse.core.resources
```

I'm trying to change name of project in the project file to match with the actual name of project progammaticaly. I imported a project from a SVN repo and then rename the folder that content this project with a new name, but if I refresh the workspace, the name in the project file doesn't change. Even if I tell him specifically :

```
IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(new Path(targetProject.replace("\\", "/") + "/.project"));
description.setName(targetProject.substring(targetProject.lastIndexOf("com.")));  // here the name in description is changed
IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());  // a get project from the actual description name that match with the folder name
if (!project.exists()) {
    project.create(description, monitor);
}
if (!project.isOpen()) {
    project.open(monitor);
}
project.setDescription(description, monitor);  // force the name in project to change
project.refreshLocal(IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE, monitor);  // refresh project in case that matter

// Check change
System.out.println(project.getDescription().equals(descritpion));  // false !
System.out.println(project.getDescription().getName().equals(description.getName())); // false !
```

It's like nothing can change this name. The name in workspace is the new name. I also try to close and open the project again but nothing happen.

What is wrong in this code ? Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this :

```
          IProjectDescription description = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().loadProjectDescription(new Path(targetProject.replace("\\", "/") + "/.project"));
          description.setName(targetProject.substring(targetProject.lastIndexOf("com.")));
          IProject project = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProject(description.getName());
          if (!project.exists()) {
            project.create(description, monitor);
          }
          if (!project.isOpen()) {
            project.open(monitor);
          }
          project.move(description, IProject.DEPTH_ONE, monitor);  // This change name
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for `IProjectDescription.setName` says:

> Setting the name on a description and then setting the description on
>   the project has no effect; the new name is ignored.
>
> Creating a new project with a description name which doesn't match the
>   project handle name results in the description name being ignored; the
>   project will be created using the name in the handle.

So you can't do this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That means I need to write in the file directly ? I don't understand what usage of the function setName can be.
In Elcipse IDE, when I rename a project, that's update the project file. This is why I think there is a method for doing it.

Comment: The name in the project description is basically ignored, I think it is probably a hang-over from very old code. Only the project name in the IProject matters.